# jsf primefaces 'updating centre panel'

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using jsf with primefaces. I succeeded in updating centre panel alone based on user's selection in side panel menu. But none of the functionalities are working.

In other words:

I have a xhtml with all menus which should appear in all pages. I am updating centre panel.
But the corresponding managed beans for the pages that are updated in centre panel are not recognized.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Code

```
public void show(){ 
  String node=selectedNode.toString(); 
  List<Pages> pagesList=loginsessinbean.findPageByTitle(node);
  linkValue = pagesList.get(0).getPagePath();    
  System.out.println("Selection=="+linkValue); displayModule();
}
public String displayModule() {
  String url="localhost:8080/MPCS-war/faces"+linkValue;
  System.out.println("URL ---"+url);
  return url;
}
```

Comment: Sample code, SW specification (server, JSF version), etc.

Comment: glass fish server, JSF 2.0

Hi, Thanks for u r quick response,

I am getting 'selectednode' value from xhtml.... to show() in my java class.
where selectednode contains the title of the page.Programatically I am getting the path of the page from title.

    public String displayModule(String selectedNode) {

        String url="http://localhost:8080/MPCS-war/faces"+selectedNode;

        return url;
    }

Comment: This is my exact code: public void show(){       
       String node=selectedNode.toString();   
   List<Pages> pagesList=loginsessinbean.findPageByTitle(node);
        linkValue = pagesList.get(0).getPagePath();
        System.out.println("Selection=="+linkValue);
        displayModule();
    }
    public String displayModule() {

        String url="http://localhost:8080/MPCS-war/faces"+linkValue;
System.out.println("URL ---"+url);
        return url;
    }

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you get an exception or error?

Comment: Hi, I am using JSF and Primefaces,
I am having a page with 3 panels. I am trying to update center panel, by means of a Tree Node. 
I am getting the path of the page for the center panel from data base by means of my Tree Managed Bean.
I am getting the page.. But after that none of the functionalities of the page is working.

Because of this I am now repainting the entire screen based on users selection from tree node and making the tree node available on each screen. But now when the screen comes the tree node is display twice.

Any suggestions...

Comment: By the way its not showing any error or exceptions

Comment: It is not possible for anybody to help you if you do not share the pieces of code (xhtml, managed bean) and state the actual problem you are facing.